# Pandas get integer keys after groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a groupby with multiple columns and the keys contain all columns which makes the output hard to read... Here's an example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import Series

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 2, 2],
                   'B': [1, 2, 2, 2],
                   'C': np.random.randn(4),
                   'D': ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']})

def aggregate(x):
    return Series(dict(C=round(x['C'].mean()), D=' '.join(x['D'])))

print(df.groupby(['A', 'B']).apply(aggregate))
```

```
       C           D
A B                 
1 1  0.0         one
  2 -1.0         two
2 2 -0.0  three four
```

How can I get 'normal' keys? Like

```
   C           D
0  0.0         one
1 -1.0         two
2 -0.0  three four
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better performance is better use [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) by `dictionary`, last add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True` for remove `MultiIndex`:

```
aggregate = {'C':lambda x: round(x.mean()), 'D':' '.join}
print(df.groupby(['A', 'B']).agg(aggregate).reset_index(drop=True))
     C           D
0  0.0         one
1  0.0         two
2  1.0  three four
```

---

If want `MultiIndex` convert to `columns` there are 2 ways:

```
print(df.groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False).agg(aggregate))
```

Or:

```
print(df.groupby(['A', 'B']).agg(aggregate).reset_index())
```

```
   A  B    C           D
0  1  1  0.0         one
1  1  2 -1.0         two
2  2  2 -1.0  three four
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reset_index` and specify the optional parameter `drop=True`. Note this removes your grouping key index entirely.

```
print(df.groupby(['A', 'B']).apply(aggregate).reset_index(drop=True))

   C           D
0  0         one
1 -1         two
2  0  three four
```